# Dropbox is automatically uploading any images saved to external SD card

Tags: android, image, dropbox

I am saving some images from an online source (JPEGs) to the external SD card under a directory like:
[External SD card]/appname/thumbnails/

I also have the DropBox app which can automatically upload photos taken by the camera, and it's uploading all the images I am saving, which is not what I want to do.

Is this a limitation of the Dropbox app, or is there some convention I am not following that is causing this to happen?

EDIT: To clarify, I am writing the program that is saving the JPEGs and I'm trying to find if I'm breaking a convention that is causing another program to think that I took a photo. After looking through some of my code (some of which I copy and pasted from examples), I saw this line and think that it may be the culprit:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());
```

Comment: This question doesn't belong stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this question doesn't belong in this forum. This is for programming. Kindly check this - [StackApps](http://stackapps.com)

Anyway, the solution to your dilemma is this.

Go to your Dropbox settings and click "Turn off Camera Upload". Dropbox will now not upload your media content directly.

Comment: To clarify, I'm writing the program that is saving the images, and I'm wondering if there's a particular convention/directory that should be followed/used when saving images (maybe the way I'm saving the image makes other programs think that it's a photo?). If this question still doesn't belong here, I will delete it. Thanks.

Comment: @noisesolo My best guess is that Dropbox uploads pics taken only by your camera, which will be saved in the DCIM folder by default. If you're using the camera to take the pictures, I'd suggest you save it in another folder. Instead of inserting it into the MediaStore why don't you use file handling to save it?

Comment: It was the use of the MediaStore that was triggering the DropBox auto-upload. Thanks for the help.